# To list or not variables in AMPscript block

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Sometimes I forget to list the variables names in the AMPscript block and they still work just fine. Can I go and not list any of them? Is there anything that can go wrong if I don't list any?

I just wanna make sure I'm not missing something here. Thanks.

e.g.

```
%%[
Var @variable1, @variable2
Set @variable1 = "something"
Set @variable2 = "something else"
]%%
```

vs.

```
%%[
Set @variable1 = "something"
Set @variable2 = "something else"
]%%
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a hit and miss. In might work in this situation but imagine having a 200 line Ampscript block and trying to debug it? You don't want to complicate things by having to check for this too.

Best practice is to declare them.

**UPDATE:**

As [Gortington](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/12730/gortonington) pointed out, defining a variable helps with handling empty or null values, reducing syntax errors

Comment: Plus defining a variable helps with handling empty or null values, reducing syntax errors.

Comment: True will update answer

Answer (score 0):

I find not declaring is reliable when working with simple IF statements and marketing content otherwise, I agree with above, though, consistency is required as best practive.